# ASP.NET - Validating Control Inside UserControl

Tags: asp.net, validation, user-controls

I have a wrapper UserControl around a DropDownList for managing language specific translation on the DropDownList values.

I also have a required field validator that is required for the inner dropdownlist.

How can I expose this control via the usercontrol to allow validation?

The error I am currently getting is as follows:

```
... cannot be validated. at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.CheckControlValidationProperty(String name, String propertyName)
      at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.ControlPropertiesValid()
```

Edit:
I'm now using...

```
[ValidationPropertyAttribute("SelectedValue")]
```

.... With

```
public string SelectedValue
{
    get { return cboI18nItems.SelectedValue; }
}
```

Which is now working if I check the IsValid property of the page on postback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Validator should be inside of your UserControl but accessible from the page.

Or set [ValidationProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.validationpropertyattribute.aspx) on the UserControl

> 1. Put the validator inside the UserControl. It can access the ID of
>      the data entry control.
> 2. Use a CustomValidator. Do not use its ControlToValidate property.
>      Instead, within your own evaluation
>      function you will access the
>      DropDownList through the UserControl.
>      You probably will make the
>      DropDownList field Public so it can be
>      seen once you typecast the UserControl
>      object to the class of that
>      UserControl.
> 3. Its possible to use the ValidationPropertyAttribute.
>      You need to add a property to your
>      usercontrol that returns a string
>      value of the data.

Found [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/868938.aspx).

Comment: Thanks the ValidationProperty worked, I was forgetting that this would be only happening on the serverside, requiring me to check for the IsValid property of the page on postback.

Comment: Thanks, The "Do not use its ControlToValidate property" did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I handled this issue a bit differently than what was suggested above.  Here is a code snippet taken from my code:

```
Protected Sub ValidateCreditCard()
    Dim validators = Page.GetValidators("cc")
    For Each v In validators
        DirectCast(v, BaseValidator).Validate()
    Next
End Sub
```

VB.NET Code but should be easy to figure out.