# How to validate WebUser Control inside Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web user control inside my page. In the web user control I have a radio button list and a required field validator to check whether any of the radio buttons are clicked or not. However, on the main page I have a button which, when clicked, should check the validation. I don't know how to do that.

Here is the structure:

```
Page -> usercontrol -> radiobuttonList
  |
  |->  button
```

When the button is clicked, I would like the web user control radiobuttonlist validator to perform its validations and set Page.IsValid accordingly.

Comment: see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106868/asp-net-validating-control-inside-usercontrol

Comment: You don't "set Page.IsValid accordingly". That property is set implicitely on `Page.Validate()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the `validationgroup` property on all your controls and button to the same string it won't matter if the validators are in separate controls or all on the one web form.

I.E `validationgroup="MyFormToValidate"`

Here is the documentation on that property:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: This is it... thanks for the info... did not know that ValidationGroup also works within the control....

Comment: Yes it does. It instructs the page Javascript which controls to validate. Just because you put your controls in a user control they all still render to the same page. It's the rendered javascript by .net that looks through the page at the validationgroup.

Comment: If this got your solution working, please mark as answered; helps future users :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [CustomValidator Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and specify the OnServerValidate method.

```
protected void cvRBLCheck_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = radiobutton.Checked;
}
```

On your button, ensure that CausesValidation is set to true.

When your button is clicked, the OnServerValidate method will fire and you can do your checks in there.

Comment: so, should i wrap my usercontrol around CustomValidatorConttol and add this _ServerValidate method in page Or in control...

Comment: I think you can put the CustomValidator and its _ServerValidate method in the control.